# ImageIcon get Parent JButton

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I have an `ImageIcon` inside of a `JButton`.  The `JButton` knows what it's "position" is relative to another Object, but the `ImageIcon` doesn't.  How can I get the `JButton` element from within the `ImageIcon` class?

I tried something like this:

```
storedPosition = getParent().getPosition();
```

but I'm getting a

> The method getParent() is undefined for the type Piece

error.

Comment: I think it isn't possible. Can you create a ImagenIconCustom (extends ImageIcon) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the JButton element from within the ImageIcon class?

Yes you can do it using [ImageIcon#getImageObserver()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImageObserver%28%29) and [ImageIcon#setImageObserver()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImageObserver%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

Sample code:

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon();
    JButton btn = new JButton(icon);

    // set the Image Observer of the ImageIcon
    icon.setImageObserver(btn);

    ...

    // get Image Observer back from ImageIcon
    JButton observer = (JButton) icon.getImageObserver();

    if (observer == btn) {
        System.out.println("We got the JButton from ImageIcon");
    }
```

output:

```
We got the JButton from ImageIcon
```